# how to log the order of operations for a node app?

Tags: node.js

i am looking for a way to log the order of operations for my node app.  similar to a stack trace, but tailored to debugging method chains vs errors. the idea is to avoid needing to add code to each function, or listen to each function explicitly. there was a way to do this in ruby, but am not seeing any clean to do this in node.

i was looking for a way to possibly tap into low level node events (or add a listener) for each time a function is called, and log the function name and arguments passed into it. does anything like this exist in node? or are there existing tools that might do something similar?

for example, without having to add code into each function,

```
var bar, baz, foo;

baz = function(b) {
  return b * 2;
};

bar = function(a, b, c) {
  return baz(a, b, c);
};

foo = function() {
  return bar(1, 2, 3);
};

foo();

// calling foo() would log...
// foo called, returns from bar
// bar called with 1, 2, 3, returns from baz
// baz called with 2, returns 4
```

Comment: Node is a single thread application, So you need to add code into each function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with javascript, however code may help you. In javascript you can wrap a function around another function like this which may help you for debugging purpose rather than duplicating the code in each function.

```
const logFunction = function(f) {
    return function() {
        console.log('Calling Function');
        const x = f.apply(null, arguments);
        console.log('Function Returns', x);
        return x;
    }    
}

const x  = logFunction(function (name) {
    console.log('Hello', name);
    return name;
});

const sum  = logFunction(function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
});

x('World');
sum(2, 3);
```

---

Results:

```
Calling Function
Hello World
Function Returns World
Calling Function
Function Returns 5
```

Comment: I was trying to work it out myself, but would this not be possible with using Proxies too?

Comment: As far I as I know, there is no such a way in js

Comment: hmm... i started looking into some kind of post processing that would essentially do something similar, but i wonder how much more difficult it will be to debug error traces. i also found this, which doesn't help this scenario, but interesting still https://github.com/eclifford/logr